# The projection to submanifold of the lie-bracket of extension of vector-fields coincide with lie-bracket of original vector-fields.

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $X,Y \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ for a submanifold $M$ of $\overline{M}$, where $(\overline{M},\overline{g})$ is a SR manifold and $(M,g)$ is a SR submanifold. Let $\overline{X},\overline{Y}$ be extensions of $X,Y$ (i.e. $\overline{X}|_{M} = X$ and $\overline{Y}|_{M} = Y)$. Then $$[\overline{X},\overline{Y}]|_{M} = [X,Y].$$ That is, $$[\overline{X},\overline{Y}] \in \mathfrak{X}(\overline{M})$$ is an extension of $$[X,Y] \in \mathfrak{X}(M).$$

Can someone point me to a proof of this, or give me one?

Here is a proof-sketch, but I believe this does not take all points into account (those in $\overline{M} \setminus M$).

*Proof*:  Let $M \subset \overline{M}$ be a submanifold of the manifold $M$, $X,Y \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ and $\overline{X},\overline{Y} \in \mathfrak{X}(\overline{M})$. We want to prove that $[\overline{X},\overline{Y}]$ is an extension of $[X,Y]$.

Since $M$ is a submanifold, by definition we know that for each $p \in M$, there exists chart $(U,\varphi)$ in $\overline{M}$ such that $$\varphi(U \cap M) = \varphi(U) \cap (\mathbb{R}^n \times \{0\}^{m-n})$$ where $m$ is the dimension of $\overline{M}$ and $n$ the dimension of $M$. Note that $[\overline{X},\overline{Y}] \in \mathfrak{X}(\overline{M})$ and that by $$[\overline{X},\overline{Y}]$$ being an extension of $[X,Y] \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, we mean that $$[\overline{X},\overline{Y}]|_M = [X,Y].$$
Now, we note that, for $p \in M$, if $$(U,\varphi = (x^1,\ldots,x^n,x^{n+1},\ldots,x^m))$$ is chart of $\overline{M}$ such that $p \in U$, that also is a submanifold chart of $M$, then $$(M \cap U, \psi = (x^1,\ldots,x^n))$$ is a chart of $M$.
We have that $$[\overline{X},\overline{Y}] = \overline{\nabla}_{\overline{X}}\overline{Y}-\overline{\nabla}_{\overline{Y}}\overline{X}$$ and since $$[\overline{X},\overline{Y}]  \in \mathfrak{X}(\overline{M})$$ we can decompose it as $$[\overline{X},\overline{Y}] = [\overline{X},\overline{Y}]^{\top}+[\overline{X},\overline{Y}]^{\perp}$$ where $$[\overline{X},\overline{Y}]^{\top} \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$$ and $$[\overline{X},\overline{Y}]^{\perp} \in \mathfrak{X}(M)^{\perp}$$ for $p \in M$, by known theorem. Again, by known definition, we have that $$ \overline{\nabla}_{X}Y := \overline{\nabla}_{\overline{X}}\overline{Y}|_M$$ for extensions $\overline{X},\overline{Y} \in \mathfrak{X}(\overline{M})$. So, we get $$[\overline{X},\overline{Y}]|_M = \overline{\nabla}_{X}Y-\overline{\nabla}_{Y}X = (\overline{\nabla}_{X}Y)^{\top}+(\overline{\nabla}_{X}Y)^{\perp}-(\overline{\nabla}_{Y}X)^{\top}+(\overline{\nabla}_{Y}X)^{\perp}$$ Now, for $X,Y \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$ we have that for a local submanifold chart $$(U \cap M, \varphi = (x^1,\ldots,x^n))$$ we have $X|_{U \cap M} = X^i \partial_i$ and $Y|_{U \cap M} = Y^i\partial_i$ where $X^i,Y^i \in C^{\infty}(U \cap N)$ this gives us that $$\Big\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^1}|_p,\ldots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x^n}|_p\Big\}$$ is a basis for the tangent space at $p \in M$. We know that we can write $$\overline{\nabla}_{X}Y = (X^i\partial_i(Y^k)+X^iY^j\overline{\nabla}_{\partial_i}\partial_j)\partial_k.$$ Now, we see that the projection onto $(T_pM)^{\perp}$ of $\overline{\nabla}_{X}Y$ must be zero, since it has no components over this subspace, hence $$(\overline{\nabla}_{X}Y)^{\perp} = 0$$  and $$(\overline{\nabla}_{Y}X)^{\perp} = 0$$ so that $$[\overline{X},\overline{Y}] = (\overline{\nabla}_{X}Y)^{\top}+(\overline{\nabla}_{Y}X)^{\top}$$ Now, since the metric on $M$, $g$, is the restriction of the metric on $\overline{M}$, $\overline{g}$, we see that for $X,Y \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, the christoffel-symbol $$\Gamma^{k}_{ij}$$ will be the same with respect to $\overline{\nabla}$ and $\nabla$ for points $p \in M$ and vector fields $X,Y \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$. Using this, our expression becomes $$(\overline{\nabla}_{X}Y)^{\top} - (\overline{\nabla}_{Y}X)^{\top} = (\overline{\nabla}_{X}Y)^{\top}+(\overline{\nabla}_{Y}X)^{\top} = \nabla_{X}Y-\nabla_{Y}X = [X,Y]$$ by the fact that $$(\overline{\nabla}_{X}Y)^{\top} = \nabla_{X}Y$$ and $$(\overline{\nabla}_{Y}X)^{\top} = \nabla_{X}Y$$
We thus get $$[\overline{X},\overline{Y}]|_M = [X,Y].$$

Comment: I disagree. The *unique* levi-civita connection is torsion free, and this is a fact I am using. The levi-civita connection needs to be metric, and this fact depends on the metric on uses.

Comment: The above comments are spot on; the metric plays no role and is a complete distraction. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4511946/568204) for the coordinate proof; and a vague allusion to the abstract coordinate-free approach using $F$-relatedness (you use it with the inclusion map). There also I suggested to take a look at Lee’s text.

Comment: also, what’s an SR manifold?

Comment: Idk, I got nearly full points on this question, the teacher took away 0.5 points because I missed points on $\overline{M} \setminus M$. 

peek-a-boo: semi-riemannian. I.e. index of metric is not neccessarily $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the input though, Mariano (and peek-a-boo).

Comment: I´ve read your proof now peek-a-boo. Mariano, maybe you are right, peek-a-boo never uses the metric.

Answer (score 1):

The lie bracket on $M$ is the restriction of the lie bracket of the extended vector fields $\overline X,\overline Y$, because the lie bracket is simply the commutator of the derivatives in direction $X$ and $Y$:
$[X,Y]f=X(Y(f))-Y(X(f))$. This object does not depend of the metric nor the connection.